# Move part of filename

Tags: ubuntu, rename, batch-rename

I have a lot of pictures in a folder named like this:

> foo.png
>   
> foo.png.~1~
>   
> foo.png.~2~
>   
> and so on

I want them to be named like

> foo.png
>   
> foo1.png
>   
> foo2.png
>   
>  and so on

How can I do this? I am using Ubuntu Server 13.04

Thanks!

-Yes, I searched before posting, but could not find anything that was helping me.

Comment: Is the number always at the end of the filename, and between `~`? Are there no other numbers in the filename? And are there just two periods in the name - one between the file and extension, and another one before the `.~2~`?

Comment: One simple answer. Yes, but there are files without .~*~ at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You loop over each file name with a bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *
do
  name=(${f//./ })      # split the filename on period. Note - the space matters!
  number=(${f//\~/ })   # similar trick to find the number between tildes
  newName=${name[0]}${number[1]}${name[1]}       # construct the new name from array elements
  echo "now you can rename " $f " to " $newName  # print out the new name as a check
done
```

I deliberately left out the "rename" command, replacing it with an "echo" instead. See if this does what you wanted - then change the `echo` line to

```
mv $f $newName
```

You might want to copy the files to a new directory, rather than doing a bulk rename, until you are sure things are behaving. I would not want to be responsible for a bunch of files getting overwritten or otherwise mangled. Of course this would be something like

```
mv $f newDirectory/$newName
```

Comment: Glad it worked. I had to learn the trick for splitting strings in bash for this answer so I got something out of it too!